What do the writings of the NKVD general Lyushkov after his defection to Japan contain?
I was recently looking at a paper about Lyushkov, an NKVD general who defected to Japan after he was recalled to Moscow where he would have been likely arrested and eventually shot.
Several Japanese who came into contact with him described him as "very bright" and "very intelligent" among other things and according to a paper about him he became a prolific writer "writing 40 pages a day".
From his writings very little remains today including these two papers which are inaccessible to me:


What do the writings of the NKVD general Lyushkov after his defection to Japan contain, does anyone know where to find them?


Actually, the latter article is accessible in English.
Lyushkov, G. S., 'Kyokuto Sekigunron' (A view of the Far Eastern Red Army), Kaizo, September 1939, pp. 148-63; excerpted in abridged translation as Lyushkoff, Gen. G. S., 'The Far Eastern Red Army', Contemporary Japan, October 1939, vol. VIII, no. 8, pp. 1022-25.
Should be at some university libraries. By request, here is an excerpt:

The endless arrests of commanders and political agents of the Red Army have brought discredit upon the remaining officers in the eyes of the men. Take, for example, the case of General Blücher. Day after day the idea that the General is an outstanding hero and a steadfast follower of Stalin, is instilled into the minds of the troops. Meanwhile, General Blücher is suddenly found missing and his portraits are torn up. When the men ask for an explanation, vague allusions are made to the effect aht the General had turned out to be a traitor to his fatherland and an enemy of the people. One can well imagine how this would affect the troops.

The main purpose of the article seems to be propaganda for the Japanese cause.

The Far Eastern Red Army [has] been supplied with more than adequate equipment and thus outwardly it presents an impressive appearance. [ . . . . however:] Due to the inferior quality of material, defects of details and other constructive faults, automobiles, rifles, tanks and machine-guns often went out of order and had to be sent back from the front. [...] Distrust of the quality of equipment became widespread in the Army, particularly among airmen who were most concerned over the matter.

He speaks of undercounted Soviet casualties in Nomonhan and vaguely concludes that the Soviets have low morale and Japan might yet defeat them. (Nomonhan was in fact an epochal defeat for the Japanese.)
He wrote a total of five articles for the famous magazine Kaizō.

April 1939: 「スターリンへの公開状」 an open letter to Stalin
May 1939: 「第十八回共産党大会批判」 critique of the 18th party congress
July 1939: 「ソ連農業問題の批判」critique of problems in Soviet agriculture
September 1939: 「極東赤軍輪」 -- "The Far Eastern Red Army," as above
December 1939: 「ソ連の対欧進出批判」 critique of Soviet expansionism in Europe

The Russian-language citation is stupidly garbled. I had to stare at it for a long time before realizing that "Gehkan Roshia" is 月刊ロシア, a Japanese magazine name. This was a monthly magazine and the 1939 April and May issues carried a long article in Japanese by Lyushkov, 「ソ連社会主義批判」 (critique of Soviet socialism). It is very poorly preserved so I can't confirm if any other articles by him were printed.
For more information see　西野辰吉著『謎の亡命者リュシコフ』三一書房, 1979

It would have been great if some online excerpts of his work were to be posted here.

@GEP ok, added an excerpt!

Very nice! Thanks. Just out of curiosity are you a native Japanese speaker?

Not truly native but I am studying Japanese history for my PhD.

That’s awesome, Avery.Best of luck with your PhD.
